# How do I print User Id in another table

Tags: java, angular, typescript

I have user entity in backend and another is feedback entity userid of user table is foreign key to feedback table. I want to print that user id in frontend part. But when I submit any feedback in database it is adding the userid correctly. IN frontend I have created table to display all feedbacks I want to print userid in that table it is coming blank.

This is my feedback entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="feedback")
public class Feedback implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "FEEDBACK_ID")
    private int feedbackid;

    @Column(name = "FEEDBACK_DATE")
    private LocalDate feedbackDate;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    @JsonIncludeProperties({"userId"})
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"userName", "firstName", "lastName",
        "dateOfBirth", "email", "mobileno", "password",
        "subscriptionStartDate", "subscriptionExpireDate", "subscriptionStatus"})
    private User user;
```

How should I write the Typescript to display user id also

Comment: You can create the model or DTO in typescript I guess to mapping the response

Comment: Yeah I created it All other data is printing properly only book Id is not printing

Comment: sorry the user id is not printing

Comment: can you edit the question and put your DTO in typescript and how you hit the API ?